# ElasticSearch - Search keyword across all fields and pair down results using filters

Tags: elasticsearch

The goal of this question is to solve a problem in regards to implementing faceted navigation in my front end. I have an input field in my UI that allows a user to query any term (full-text) across all fields/all indices. I would also like the user to be able to pair the results down using faceted navigation (e.g., filters).

For example, if a user searches for the keyword "thomson", that should search across all fields. Then the user will be presented with two (or more) checkboxes representing filters (let's say a 'Geographic Location' and a 'Group') -- this should be an AND filter. I've tried the following ElasticSearch query to no avail.

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
        "must": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "thomson",
                "fields": ["*"]
            }
        },
         "should":[
            {
               "terms":{
                  "geographicLocation": ["USA", "ENGLAND"]
               }
            },
            {
               "terms":{
                  "Group": ["AA", "BB"]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

So let's say I have the following documents in ES:

```
{ name: 'Joe', street: '3 thomson st', geographicLocation: 'USA', Group: 'AA' }
{ name: 'Thomson': street: '1 york ave', geographicLocation: 'CHINA', Group: 'BB' }
{ name: 'Jane', street: '2 jones dr' geographicLocation: 'ENGLAND', Group: 'CC' }
```

First, I should only get results that have 'thomson' somewhere in the fields (e.g., the first two docs above). Then, those should be filtered down by geographicLocations that are either "USA" or "ENGLAND" AND Group that is either "AA" or "BB".

So I want documents with 'thomson' somewhere in the document that have a geographicLocation of either USA or ENGLAND AND are either in Group AA or BB. This leaves me with only with the first document.

I'm having an impossible time managing the above ES params to get that to work.

EDIT: Here is my mapping:

```
{
  "person": {
    "mappings": {
      "TEST": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "street": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "EndDate": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "EndDt": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "Group": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "d3232b0e1b28bfb8b432a3459404676d:created_date": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "d3232b0e1b28bfb8b432a3459404676d:edited": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "geographicRegion": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you don't move both of the should clauses inside the must one?

Comment: I updated the query to the following and it doesn't seem to give me any hits: 

{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "must": [
    { "multi_match": { "query": "thomson", "fields": ["*"] } },
    { "terms": { "geographicLocation": ["USA", "ENGLAND"] } }, 
    { "terms": { "Group": ["AA", "BB"] } }
   ]
  }
 }
}

Comment: Can you also share the mapping of your index? I suspect that your `geographicLocation` and `Group` fields are analyzed strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the two should clauses inside the must clause

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
        "must": ,
         "must":[
            {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "thomson",
                    "fields": ["name", "street"]
                }
            },
            {
               "terms":{
                  "geographicLocation.keyword": ["USA", "ENGLAND"]
               }
            },
            {
               "terms":{
                  "Group.keyword": ["AA", "BB"]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val. Unfortunately I'm getting an 'parse_exception' error. The reason given: "failed to parse date field [thomson] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]". Could this be because of the star search searching on fields formatted as something other than a string? Searching on '_all' seems to work when doing a regular search.

Comment: I've updated the query, what do you get now? Also see my second comment on your question.

Comment: Edited my original question with my mapping. The updated query doesn't throw an exception anymore but not actually getting any hits.

Comment: I've updated my query, you simply need to use the `.keyword` sub-fields instead and you'll be ok.

Comment: Yup that worked! It also works if I search the terms in lowercase. I believe the mapping should set the analyzer option to not analyze. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, if you didn't have the `keyword` fields, I would have suggested to search for lowercase values, but it's better to use the keyword fields in your case